# Unable to write contact photo in vcf using ez-vcard0.9.5 in android

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, vcf-vcard

I am reading contact information from device and writing in a vcf file using ez-vcard0.9.5. When I restore the file, it does not restore contact photo.

I read the photo from device contact using following code:

```
public static byte[] getContactPictureByte(Context context,ContentResolver cr, Cursor cur, String id) throws IOException {

    Bitmap photo = null;
    InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(id)));

    byte[] b = null;
    if (inputStream != null) {
        photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        b = baos.toByteArray();
        Log.v("photo","b.lemgth: " + b.length);
        inputStream.close();
    }
    return b;
}
```

And then added the returned byte array to vcf.

```
pictureByte = ContactUtils.getContactPictureByte(context,cr, cur, id);
vcard.addPhoto(new Photo(pictureByte, ImageType.JPEG));
String vcardText = Ezvcard.write(vcard).version(VCardVersion.V3_0).go();
```

When I opened the vcf file using notepad I found the the value of "photo" tag is too long and it continues till the end of file while the vcf format is missing its ending tag and other informations.
The photo tag started like this

PHOTO;TYPE=PNG;ENCODING=b:/9j/4AAQSk............[till ending]

Can anyone kindly give me the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're looking at the correct file?  Your code sample is generating a string, not writing to a file.  Also, ez-vcard writes the value of the TYPE parameter in lower-case, so if ez-vcard wrote it, it should look like this: `PHOTO;TYPE=png;ENCODING=b:`